# Dropzone ajax response with custom variables

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, dropzone.js

I have a form that uploads images in dropzone, and when it uploads it records the names of the images to a mysql database and assigns them the id of a product. I return that id with a json array, but I don't know where I can retrieve it to redirect to another page

`

```
$data = array(
    'id_producto' => $id_producto, 
    );

//returns data as JSON format
echo json_encode($data);
```

```
Here I try to retrieve the json variablez

    Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {

    url: '/php/upload_photos.php',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 10,
    maxFiles: 10,
    maxFilesize: 3,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    dictDefaultMessage: "Please drag & drop images here",
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    init: function() {        
        var dzClosure = this;
        
        $('.error').hide();
        document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
                        
            dzClosure.processQueue();

        });
                

        this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) { 
        
            $("form").find("input").each(function(){
                formData.append($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
                
                formData.append("id_grupo", $("#id_grupo").val());
                formData.append("id_personal", $("#id_personal").val());
                
            });

        });

        },
        

    success: function (file, data) {
       $('#id_producto').val(data.id_producto);
       var id_producto = $('#id_producto').val() 
       // window.location="restable.php?id_producto="+id_producto

    },

    error: function (file, data) {
    }

        
        
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

you must use dropzone in this way:

```
$("#BannerUpload").dropzone({
    init: function () {},

    removedfile: function (file) {// when remove action invokes },

    success: function (file, response) {
       $('#id_producto').val(response.id_producto);
       var id_producto = $('#id_producto').val() 
       window.location="restable.php?id_producto=response.id_producto

    },

    error: function (file, response) {
    }

});
```

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry, the answer didn't work. It doesn't load the variable $("#id_producto")

Comment: Does `response.id_producto` return value? What's the `#id_producto` Id of? what type is the element?

Comment: Thanks for your interest... that INT type variable... update the code to be more illustrative... {"id_producto":1303} this is the response in the console

Comment: Use this :`window.location="restable.php?id_producto="+ response.id_producto`

Comment: So `response.id_producto` works correctly. You are getting value of `$(#id_product)` . Is it a input ? You can use `val`  for input

Comment: yes it is an input...

Comment: id_producto=undefined...  thanks a lot anyway...

Comment: Doesn't work? `window.location="restable.php?id_producto="+ response.id_producto`